# Cygwin -How do Install new packages?

Tags: installation

I know im supposed to run the setup again to install new packages but when i do (im trying to install the gcc and make package) it doesn't install it and when i go to use cygwin i still can use the the make command for example. When i go back to the setup it shows that they're not installed and if i try to install them again the same thing happens, anyway i can fix this? Im on windows btw.

Answer (score 0):

A possible error in your situation is that you have selected a wrong installation folder and that there are several versions installed.

Installing new packages on cygwin involves these key steps:

- run the cygwin setup.exe binary
- select install from internet
- select where to install and where to save downloaded packages
- select ftp
- browse packages and click on the version numbers (or Skip/Keep) to select the desired one.
- click next

It's really simple and I can't imagine you got it wrong. Perhaps there is a conflict between the "for me alone" and "for all users" options?